# npm Error on build script in package.json "Syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I recently tried to set up a react app while following a YouTube tutorial.
I've looked through other articles but cannot find exactly what the problem is with my syntax. [Here is an image of my the various folders and files that make up the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE9kP.png)

```
webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline"
```

Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "reactenv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Enviroment",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && copy src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs"
  ],
  "author": "Lee Warner",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Run your commands one by one (not combining them by &&), to know which one cases an error

Comment: Just did and the copy command needed qoutes, now theres an error saying "Cannot find the file specified"

Comment: I think I need to find a new tutorial -_- this is filled with errors, nothing works until I install webpack and then webpack-dev-server every time I want to open the project, and then copy only works in the vs code terminal and not anywhere else however, it doesnt work when I just run npm start